# Should this question have been closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264875/how-do-i-add-formatted-code-to-a-microsoft-word-document-closed) about using “MS-Word” for formatting source code was migrated to Super User.

However:

- It is a problem that a lot of programmers will have
- It is not a problem that a non-programmer will have
- Therefore it is very unlikely that a SU user would know the answers, but it is possible that a StackOverflow user would know the answers.

Therefore should the question have been closed?

---

Or to put it another way.

Is StackOverflow for:

- Only questions about programming
- Or also questions that only a programmer will have

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it should have been migrated to SU.  It is a question about document formatting and is not necessarily a question only a programmer would have.  Technical writers, for example, who don't program can also have this question as well as editors, layout designers, etc.  There's nothing there about actually writing code, just how to display it in a document.

Answer (score 4):

Not only it is not suitable for http://stackoverflow.com, it [is a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760121/is-there-a-way-for-elegant-source-code-listings-in-openoffice-org-writer).

Comment: Voting to close as belongs on superuser...

Comment: It's missing one vote... Anyone care to join in?

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of close votes... again.

Comment: Added the final vote...

Comment: @Voyager: `OpenOffice != Word`

Comment: @Chester: For small values of `!=`. The solutions and largely the steps to reproduce them are similar.

Answer (score 3):

I also say, "Yes", but not exactly because it's not programming related.  It belongs on SuperUser because the meat of the question is about document formatting, and therefore *it's more likely to get a good answer on SuperUser*, as SuperUser is more targeted to things like document formatting.

Comment: I wouldn't say Super User is targeted at things like "document formatting". Rather at things like "document formatting using local software" ;-)

Comment: Yeah. Super User is for all things computery *except* programming, system and network administration, games, using websites, building website, flamewars, holy wars, and probably one or two things I missed. But other than that *everything*. And *He's* the People Front of Judea. **Splitter!**

Comment: @dmckee: Then where am I supposed to go with my `vim` vs. EMACS holy war?

Comment: @voyager:  You get the pitchforks, I'll get the torches.

Comment: Bye, bye boys. Have fun storming the castle.

Comment: @dmckee - do you think it'll work?

Comment: @Joel, only if they have a wheel-barrel.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, the question has been rightfully closed.

I don't think this is particular to programmers, as there are other kind of blocks of text (other than code) with some kind of different formatting which can be scattered around in a word document. So the answer basically applies to those as well:

- copy the text into a program which does the formatting
- apply the formatting to it
- copy it back to word

Comment: yes, but the "program which does the formatting" must understand source code and so A programmer will only wish to use it.

Comment: @Ian: It was in parenthesis, I admit, but I *did* say **other than code**.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have voted to migrate that question. Formatting source code in word processors may not be directly programming related, but folks, *come on.* 
We have thousands and thousands of HTML related questions every day that could just as well have been asked by a designer (as opposed to a programmer). In fact, if you look closely, many of them *have* been asked by a designer. Not that I mind this at all - I'm happy about the HTML and CSS tags on Stack Overflow - but it should serve to give some perspective here.

Comment: Yes, we should vote to close on those too!

Comment: @Downvoter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=html&sort=newest&pagesize=50 good luck!

Comment: `*chuckle*`  Still hold to my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Programmers also have questions about programming careers that aren't really about the activity of programming, merely the things surrounding the activity of programming.

The question being considered is not about the activity of programming.  It is, instead, about branching away from the activity of coding and taking a code product into another domain - that of word processing.

From that point on the code is non-executable (unless copied back into the programming domain), and is meant only for presentation and human-readable purposes.  Any activities surounding the code are word processing activities, not programming activities.

Comment: does that include tools like stylecop?

Comment: @Ian Ringrose - It depends.  If it's just a question on how to use stylecop alone, then I'd say that's a support request for the manufacturer.  If it's a question on how to integrate it into the checkin/build/test/validation process then it'd be programming related.  If its a question about using it to reformat code for printed publication, then it's a word processing question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is StackOverflow for:
>
> - Only questions about programming
> - Or also questions that only a programmer will have

It's only for questions about programming.

I'm a programmer, and have plenty of questions about the meaning of life, but I don't ask them in SO

Comment: The answer is 42.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085959/

Comment: The answer is clearly 0x2A.

Comment: Except that the meaning of life is important to everybody, not just programmers.  SO is certainly not for anything a programmer might wonder about, or anything important for a programmer, but a fair number of the 3K+s seem to think it's applicable to things that are specifically applicable to programmers.