# Should this closed question be reopened?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994379/how-do-i-create-objects-from-dom-parser-in-java) was closed by the community.

I don't agree this it wasn't a real question, I admit it wasn't a *good* question, but it is a *real* question.

Obviously the OP doesn't know how Java `Object`s work, I don't think that that should lead to the question being closed.

The question itself is fairly clear. What the OP wants to do is laid out clearly at top (read some XML objects into Java `Object`s, though not in those words) and the OP posted some code to demonstrate that they tried to solve the issue.

So, my question is: Should this question have been closed and if so why? (And if it shouldn't have been closed maybe it should be reopened...).

P.S. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41748/214894) meta answer recommended that posting here was the right approach if I did not agree with a close decision.

Comment: Agreed. As programmer (not Java, but still) it's totally valid question that show effort and research. Looks like too many users adopts "Guilty Until Proven Innocent" approach.

Comment: Yes, you are right to post this here. I have voted to reopen, though I can see what might have motivated the closers. Reading through it, it did read somewhat like a "do my work for me" question. But in this particular case, I think that's caused by the formulation rather than that it's what the OP intends. For me there is enough effort to see this reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the question deserves to be re-opened and this has now happened.

However, after you voted to re-open the question appeared [in the re-open queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1918647). I had to spend a fair amount of time working out why on earth someone would vote to re-open this question before deciding to vote that way myself.

No-one else in the queue agreed with me; and 5 people originally voted to close. In cases like this it's often better to work out *why* the question was closed in the first place *before* voting to re-open.

If you look at the original question it initially reads like the OP is asking *"do my work for me"*, here's a massive code dump. The question itself is not like that and a simple edit, [as Bart has done](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15994379/revisions), moving the XML out of the code block helps massively.

Yes, the closed question should be re-opened. However, *before* voting please fix the question and make it easier to understand; the normal processes may then work without any special effort being required. If you're feeling really nice you could comment to the OP explaining your edit and helping them to write better questions.

Comment: understood. Maybe the close votes were a little trigger happy in this case but understandable. I will try and edit questions I think should be reopened to make them more clear.

Answer (score 0):

"Not a real question" means the question is too vague or broad to be answered. That question is asking about a specific case, and it shows the code used by the OP.

If the question didn't show the code, I would close it as not a real question, but this is not the case. I reserve that closing reason to questions similar to "How do I write a Drupal module?"